# Waiting for Jobs Launched by Other Jobs to Finish

Tags: multithreading, powershell, jobs

### Goal

I'm trying to use PowerShell to process files in parallel while limiting the number of currently executing processes. If the list of files to process were known at the start of execution, a [queue](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/04/04/scaling-and-queuing-powershell-background-jobs/) could be used to achieve this.

However, this script needs to accommodate files added to the "to process" directory while the script is running. The way I'm attempting to achieve this is by having each job, upon completion, remove itself and then call the function that checks for files to process/launches new jobs.

### Problem

The difficulty I've encountered is getting PowerShell to wait for processing to finish before exiting.

Using `Get-Job | Wait-Job` appears to cause blocking. That is, the script *never* returns unless I manually intervene. In ISE, after `$maxConcurrentJobs` number of files are processed, I have to press Ctrl+C it in order to get the rest of the files processed and to allow the script to exit.

Using a while loop works as desired in PowerShell ISE. However, in PowerShell (command-line), the while loop approach only processes `$maxConcurrentJobs` number of files—that is, any additional files in "to process" never get processed. Apparently, when the first set of processing jobs finishes, the next set are not launched.

```
While ($true) {
    if ((Get-Job | Where-Object { $_.PSJobTypeName -eq 'BackgroundJob' }).Count -eq 0) { break; }
    Start-Sleep -s 1
}
```

### Question

How can I wait for all my script's jobs to complete without the script blocking or exiting prematurely?

---

### Code

```
function StartProcessingFile([IO.FileInfo]$file) {
    $destination = "$PSScriptRoot\Processed\$((get-date).ToString('yyyyMMdd-HHmmss'))-$($file.BaseName).csv"
    $inputFile = Move-Item $file.FullName -Destination $destination -PassThru

    Start-Job -Name $file.Name -ScriptBlock { param($x) Start-Sleep -s 10; } -ArgumentList $inputFile # In real life, ScriptBlock will call a PowerShell cmdlet that processes the file
}

$maxConcurrentJobs = 2;
function ProcessFiles {
    While ((Get-Job | Where-Object { $_.PSJobTypeName -eq 'BackgroundJob' }).Count -lt $maxConcurrentJobs) {
        $file = Get-ChildItem -Path "$PSScriptRoot\ToProcess" *.csv | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime | Select-Object -First 1
        if ($file -eq $null) { break }

        $job = StartProcessingFile($file)
        Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $job -EventName StateChanged  -Action { Unregister-Event $eventsubscriber.SourceIdentifier; Remove-Job $eventsubscriber.SourceIdentifier; Remove-Job $eventsubscriber.SourceObject; ProcessFiles; } | Out-Null
    }
}

ProcessFiles

While ($true) {
    Get-Job
    Write-Host
    if ((Get-Job | Where-Object { $_.PSJobTypeName -eq 'BackgroundJob' }).Count -eq 0) { break; }
    Start-Sleep -s 1
}

#Get-Job | Wait-Job
```

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, I edited the paragraph containing that sentence to clarify. Does that help?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, I want it to block until the all files are processed and then exit. Problem is that the script *never* exits (on its own).

Comment: Ahh, sorry, I totally misinterpreted that. Is it a hard requirement that you only ever process 2 files at once? If so, using a `RunspacePool` with a max count of 2 might be a better approach. If not, `Get-Job | Wait-Job` will work fine